# Find the minimal element and then return the index of the column in which that minimal element is

Tags: c

```
int min(int matrix[][MAX], int n){
    int i, j;
    int minimal=matrix[0][0];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<n;j++){
            if(matrix[i][j]<minimal){
                minimal=matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return minimal;
}
```

This is how I started, and I find it a problem how to return the index of the column which contains the minimal element.

Comment: Good job finding the minimal! But you're not returning what the problem states. So how do you think you could return the index of the column in which that minimal element is?

Comment: Why `for(j=1;j<n;j++)`? What about the column 0?

Comment: I have declared    int minimal=matrix[0][0]; so if I am looking for an element that is smaller that the minimal, I want to skip the minimal element, so that is why the second loop starts form 1 .

Comment: If the minimal is in column 0, but in another row (not row 0), then you'll not find it, right?

Comment: @Rocky G.  It is not clear whether you need only to find the column where the minimumj element is or you have to return the minimum element itself and the column.

Comment: It was just the column :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use another variable `column` to keep track of the column where the minimal element is. Every time you find a new minimal element, update the column value.

```
int column=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(matrix[i][j]<minimal){
            column=j;
            minimal=matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
return column;
```

EDIT: `j` should begin from `0` as pointed by @ericbn in the comments.